# Eclipse is adding another bracket before auto close bracket

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, brackets, auto-close

I keep going back and forth between Eclipse ide and Netbeans ide for java programing. The reason being is that I love the way Eclipse is set up and all, but the thing I hate about it is I can't figure out how to not add another bracket if theres already one there. I know that might be difficult to understand but this is an example...I was typing this code out earlier:

```
int sheetPixel = ((y + yOffset) & 7) * sheet.width + ((xMin + xOffset) & 7);
```

I only typed some of that line, then went back to the tutorial I was watching to understand the code some more, then finished typing it, but by the time I got to the end of my code, I had about 3 parenthesis.  If I was in Netbeans, if a parenthesis is the next character, the cursor would just jump over it and not place another one there. For ex..

is where my cursor would be. It's not related in any way to code. Just trying to show the best way I can think of.

Netbeans:

int sheetPixel = () if i type ')' then i would end up with ().

Eclipse:

int sheetPixel = () if i type ')' then sometimes I would end up with ()) and other times I would end up with ()

Is there a way to change this to get the result like netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this  in
 **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor**

Comment: I thought I looked though there.

Comment: Where exactly? I see only "Bracket highlighting" there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check
edit-->.smart insert mode

if its disable ,enable and try

Comment: It is enabled. It seems to happen whenever I leave the page and come back

Comment: now check Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor--.>TYping Check what you have enabled in Automatically insert at correct position.Have  you disabled braces

Comment: I have both Semicolons and Braces checked.